How the deployer manages to call function manual swap on a burned liquidity renounced contract and drain more money selling tokens he didn't hold
Deployer sold his tokens and left the project. 10 days later I verify he made another sell from tokens that weren't on his deployer wallet. He called a function "manual swap" and somehow I see he managed to get a portion of paired liquidity with his token and eth and there's still more liquidity that's burned and I wonder if he can continue to call this manual swap function to keep somehow selling the liquidity.
I found this on his contract the tokens contract and I wonder if he somehow using a tax contract to breach the liquidity?
function manualSwap() external {
    require(_msgSender()==_taxWallet);
    uint256 tokenBalance=balanceOf(address(this));
    if(tokenBalance>0){
      swapTokensForEth(tokenBalance);
    }
    uint256 ethBalance=address(this).balance;
    if(ethBalance>0){
      sendETHToFee(ethBalance);
    }
}

Please help.. I wanna know if I should stay away.
THE token is Called $BTC ticker
And we thought after the dev left it was safe
Here the token contract address
0x300E0d87f8c95d90CFe4b809BAa3a6c90E83b850
Here the contract holding the liquidity that's allegedly and verifiably burned
0x3fD349f3D99970DfE553Ca04e37E066be955c1a5
And here the deployer thief still finding ways to get more from holders
0x645a46F413d51fE8D13B5Fa9A521b5c2effE1995
